# Uncheck Excel form control checkboxes with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to uncheck the checkboxes of selected cells.

This code unchecks the checkboxes of all the sheet. I need to uncheck only the checkboxes of a specified selection.

```vb
Sub Unchecker()
    Dim chkBox As Excel.CheckBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each chkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        chkBox.Value = xlOff
    Next chkBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleas try it.

```vb
Sub Unchecker()
    Dim chkBox As Excel.CheckBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each chkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        ' Top-left of CheckBox is in Selection
        If Not Intersect(chkBox.TopLeftCell, Selection) Is Nothing Then _
            chkBox.Value = xlOff
    Next chkBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```